# Dependence of partial derivative on continuity of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can we say that partial derivative for a function always exist?? I am specifically in doubt , if for example we use the limit definition for partial derivative and we get it to be infinity, what can we say about the partial derivative??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it doesn't always exist. (Just like the ordinary derivative of a function of one variable doesn't always exist.)

Comment: Thanks...but can you provide a more detailed answer like by using some example

Comment: Just take any example that you like from the one-variable case... For example, $f(x,y)=|x|+\sqrt[3]{y}$ doesn't have partial derivatives at the point $(0,0)$.